# Fractional number of wavelengths around a loop?

Tags: atomic-physics, wavelength

I am studying Modern Physics from Arthur Beiser's book 5th edition.

And in chapter 4.4: The Bohr Atom, he says:

**"If a fractional number of wavelengths is placed around the loop, destructive interference will occur as the waves travel around the loop, and the vibrations will die out rapidly."**

I thought only waves with opposite phase results in destructive interference.

*Maybe this is something really trivial, but I don't understand how "fractional number of wavelengths = a wave without full period" results in destructive interference ?*

Answer (score 4):

Their explanation seems like a poor one to me. It doesn't make a lot of sense, both for the reason you gave and because the real issue is whether we can make a single wave pattern that is a solution to the Schrodinger equation, not whether we can make it by superimposing a wave on itself as it wraps around.

A better explanation might be the following. The wavefunction can't be discontinuous, and it must also be twice differentiable (i.e., not have a kink in it). A discontinuity or kink would be a point where the particle has infinite kinetic energy. (It's like a zero wavelength.) For this reason, we need a whole number of wavelengths, so that when the wavefunction wraps around on itself, there will be no discontinuity or kink.

Comment: Ben: this textbook should be banned as an honest effort to oversimplification that grossly backfired.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  So, in this context: we don't want discontinuity. Fractional number of wavelengths means discontinuous wave function, and a whole number of wavelengths means full wavelength.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero maybe only this part of the topic is too much simplified.

Comment: @ZulfidinKhodzhaev We used that textbook for a while and kept on finding all manners of errors and poorly supported explanations in it (not typos).  Take it with a grain of salt and do not hesitate to consult another text.

Comment: Have at it: http://phy240.ahepl.org/Concepts_of_Modern_Physics_by_Beiser.pdf

Comment: @JEB I hope it is not copyright infringement :)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That's really helpful to hear. I will keep in mind.